# if and else with vector sum condition not properly working

Tags: r, if-statement, radix

I have a `data.frame` called `sites_sp` where I'm trying to run some functions based on `if` and `else` statements. `sites_sp` has the following structure:

```
structure(list(x = c(-50.1298257841559, -49.9523708108406, -49.8600298829818, 
-49.8590735594872, -49.8600022102151, -49.680556540172), y = c(-29.2498490060132, 
-29.1594734717135, -29.0700140387022, -28.9795033961473, -28.8900003372153, 
-28.8945716273705), ua = c("ua_1", "ua_4", "ua_10", "ua_15", 
"ua_21", "ua_23"), occ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PC1 = c(0.403336553595704, 
-0.209623013249306, -2.38969068562858, -1.0875631345167, 0.0424075103800285, 
-1.69180948954307), PC2 = c(-3.62346919232857, -4.03856503375702, 
-1.46862258765078, -1.77908267718137, -2.0250031837701, -0.952927464794925
), PC3 = c(-0.375601733371977, -0.122982261539736, -0.365818414058142, 
-0.111150398019996, 0.287459840686463, 0.034973266100254), PC4 = c(-1.31153262462204, 
-0.899941801783298, -1.35652371929479, -1.98693913441246, -1.75393016363327, 
-0.788097574287776), PC5 = c(1.42830395246321, 1.55155187773266, 
1.33933059031444, 0.0760013457702872, 0.588191290690648, -0.408003273953271
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'm doing is an `if` and `else` statements of form:

```
for(s in sp){ 
 
if(sum(sites_sp$occ >= 30)){

     pa_data <- st_as_sf(sites_sp, 
                    coords = c("x", "y"), 
                    crs = crs(env_terra))
    ...

    } else {

    block of functions for the statement being FALSE

    }

}
```

**RELEVANT EDIT: From what I can tell, the function is going directly to the `else` block even though it should not — since `sum(sites_sp$occ)` is bigger than 30 for the first `s in sp`**

I can't really understand what's going on. If I try `sum(sites_sp$occ)` it returns for me a value of 37, implying that the function inside the `if` block (`pa_data <- st_as_sf()...`) should run normally. What am I doing wrong here? If more information is needed, please tell me.

Comment: (1) Nice start of sample data, but it's a bit more difficult (and incomplete) to use as-is, can you add the output from `dput(head(sites_sp))`? (2) Do we need to know how to create `sites_sp`, or is its generation from `sites` just nice-to-know? I don't see how it applies to your question. (3) You are showing code that implements `if`-and-`else`, nothing there suggests you are using `ifelse`, which is very different. (4) Since your wish for a conditional relies on `occ` being some variety of values, it would help if your sample data contains a variety above/below your threshold. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I edited a bit my data. And you're right, I'm not running `ifelse`, but `if` and `else` separately. The `occ` vector is 1 and 0 only (presence-absence). Before, I was running the function normally without `if` and `else`. I had to add those conditions to better analyse my data.

Comment: Thank you for changing your data format!

Comment: No problem! I edited everything a bit. If anything is still needed, please tell me.

Comment: At least in your sample data, all `sites_sp$occ` are 0, so `sum(sites_sp$occ)` is of course < 30 and will default to the `else` statement.

Comment: That's because most of the values are 0, but I can guarantee there are 1s there too. See above, the first species of the loop:
`
> summary(sites_sp$Abarema.langsdorffii)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.08241 0.00000 1.00000 
> sum(sites_sp$Abarema.langsdorffii)
[1] 37`

Comment: Guys, the weirdest thing is that I can manually run the functions inside the `if` block, and they work properly like before I started using `if` and `else`. Wtf really. Is just a simply `sum` as statement. I don't get it.

Comment: I tried the reverse now: `if(sum(sites_sp$occ <= 30))` and now the `occ` that should be outside of the `if` is working inside and vice-versa WTF

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys...I'm kinda dumb.

The problem is simply here:

`if(sum(sites_sp$occ >= 30)){`

Should be written as

`if(sum(sites_sp$occ) >= 30){`

My condition was inside the `sum`